# How to Merge Two Dates in EJB JPA

Tags: java, jpa, ejb-3.0, java-ee-6

I am try to Merge Two Dates, Current Date and Another Date in EJB With the help of JPA
it's my class UserBean 
in this class i am prepare one method setExpireDate.
This Method are use for merge two dates like a one CurrentDate{`new Date()`} and another Date
{`new Date(1,6,0)`}

```
    @Stateless(mappedName = "CMS/UserBean")
public class UserBean implements UserBeanLocal {

    @PersistenceContext(name = "CMS-ejbPU")
    EntityManager em;
@Override
    public boolean setExpireDate(int userId,int planId) 
    {
        try
        {
            EntityBean.User usr = em.find(EntityBean.User.class, userId);


            int day = 20;
            int month = 6;
            int year = 0;

            Date expr = new Date() + new Date(year, month, day);


            usr.setExpireDate(expr);
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error are Occure, While Setting the ExpireDate");
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: This doesn't compile. COuld you explain us what you mean by "merging two dates"? And what does it have to do with JPA?

Comment: i am just try to add one date in another date
like i am add 1 month 2day  3year in current date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using joda-time to handle dates, which is a much better API than what the JDK comes with.

To manipulate dates with the standard JDK classes, you use the Calendar class:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); // now
calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 2);
calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, 3);
Date result = calendar.getTime();
```